# $scope is not getting the ng-model html value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my controller file

```
'use strict';

cms.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $window) {



     $scope.registerClinic = function () {
       var dataParam={
                "primaryEmailId": $scope.data1.emai
                 }
         console.log(angular.toJson(dataParam));     
    $http({
    url:  "/cms/sign-up",
    method: "POST",
    headers :{'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json' },
    data: dataParam
    })

        .success(function(response) {
    console.log(angular.toJson(response));


                    });
    };  






});
```

Here is my Html file
in my html file there is ng-model="data1.emai" value when
i want to parse it through a form in a controller it is not happening

```
<body>

<div class="modal-dialog" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
     <div class="modal-body login metrial">


        <div class="modal-body login metrial">



        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign up</h4> 

           <form id="loginform2" ng-submit="registerClinic()" name="loginform2" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="email" placeholder="Email ID" ng-class="{'invalid-field': loginform2.emai.$touched || loginform2.$submitted, 'valid-field': loginform2.emai.$valid}" 
                                ng-model="data1.emai" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,}$/" type="text" required>
                                <span ng-show="loginform2.emai.$touched && loginform2.emai.$error.pattern" class="error-geni">Invalid email</span>
            <!--  <label class="field-title">Email ID</label> -->
                        </div> 
                    <div class="margin-bottom-20">  
                            <div style="width:20%" class="input-group-addon-signup">
                                <input value="+91"  disabled="" type="text"></div>
                            <div class="input-group-addon-signup"><input id="mobil" ng-class="{'invalid-field': loginform2.mobil.$touched || loginform2.$submitted, 'valid-field': loginform2.mobil.$valid}" onkeypress="return isNumber(event,'mobil');" placeholder="Mobile No" type="text"
                                ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" name="mobil" maxlength="10" ng-model="data1.mobil" ng-pattern="/^$|^[0-9X]{10}$/" required>
                                <span ng-show="loginform2.mobil.$touched && loginform2.mobil.$error.pattern" class="error-geni"> Invalid Mobile Number </span> </div>
             <!-- <label class="field-title">Mobile No</label>-->
                    </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="clinic"  ng-model="data1.clinic" placeholder="Clinic Name" type="text">
            <!--  <label class="field-title">Clinic Name</label> -->
          </div> 

       <select class="form-group" id="subscriptionplans" ng-model="data.Subscription" value="Subscription">
         <option id="optionspec">Trial Subscription</option>
            <option value="0">Silver</option>
            <option value="1">Gold</option>
            <option value="1">Platinum</option>
       </select>

            <div class="form-group">
            <input name="signupPassword" id="signupPassword" placeholder="Password"  ng-class="{'invalid-field': loginform2.signupPassword.$touched || loginform2.$submitted, 'valid-field': loginform2.signupPassword.$valid}"  ng-model="data1.signupPassword"
            ng-minlength="8"  ng-maxlength="20"  type="password" required>
            <span ng-show="loginform2.signupPassword.$touched && loginform2.signupPassword.$error.minlength || loginform2.signupPassword.$touched && loginform2.signupPassword.$error.maxlength"  class="error-geni">Password must be 8-20 characters long and must have at least one uppercase character & one number and can have special characters -_/#@</span>
            </div>


          <!--confirm Password-->
           <div class="form-group">
           <input name="docPassword2" id="docPassword2" ng-class="{'invalid-field': loginform2.docPassword2.$touched || loginform2.$submitted, 'valid-field': loginform2.docPassword2.$valid}" placeholder="Confirm Password" 
            ng-model="data1.docPassword2"
            class="gui-input" required ng-compare="loginform2.signupPassword"
            ng-disabled="!loginform2.signupPassword.$valid" type="password"/>

            <span ng-show="loginform2.docPassword2.$touched && loginform2.docPassword2.$error.compare1" class="error-geni">Password Mismatch </span> 
            </div>


           <button type ="submit" class="btn pull-right" type="button">SIGN UP</button>
 </form> 

        </div> 
       </div>
    </div>  



</body>
```

EDIT : i tried to access through data1.emai it error

```
angular.min.js:108 TypeError: Cannot read property 'emai' of undefined
    at n.$scope.registerClinic (home-controller.js:37)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:212), <anonymous>:4:262)
    at f (angular.min.js:252)
    at n.$eval (angular.min.js:134)
    at n.$apply (angular.min.js:135)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:252)
    at HTMLFormElement.c (angular.min.js:35)is saying
```

I cant understand why my value is not going under $scope in controller through html

EDIT when i am deleting all the values from input

it is working.. but not found the exact problem

Comment: you have data1.emai in your ng-model attribute

Comment: also added that still cant access

Answer (score 2):

you access it from the scope like this:

```
"primaryEmailId": $scope.emai
```

while in the template you bind it that way:

```
 ng-model="data1.emai"
```

You need to have data1 object in the scope to make it consistent, e.g.:

```
"primaryEmailId": $scope.data1.emai
```

Comment: while following you second approach 
this gives an error 


`angular.min.js:108 TypeError: Cannot read property 'emai' of undefined
    at n.$scope.registerClinic (home-controller.js:37)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:212), <anonymous>:4:262)
    at f (angular.min.js:252)
    at n.$eval (angular.min.js:134)
    at n.$apply (angular.min.js:135)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:252)
    at HTMLFormElement.c (angular.min.js:35)`

Comment: try defining it in your controller, e.g. $scope.data1 = { emai: "default@email.com" };

Answer (score 0):

initialize the `$scope.data1` object in controller,

```
cms.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.data1 = {};
    .....
}
```

hope this helps.